# max() in mysql returns 9999 not more than that?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a customers tables where there is a field called `uniqueId` Type : `varchar(255)` & Collation : `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`  ..I wanted to find the max uniqueId ..though i have entry of 10000 but it always return 9999 ..why is that?

```
SELECT MAX(uniqueId) FROM `customers`
```

Comment: MySQL is 0 based.

Comment: On a `varchar` column lexical ordering is used, not numeric. If you want numeric ordering, use a numeric type!

Comment: Because you don't have 99999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could be you have a string then try cast

```
SELECT MAX( CAST(uniqueId AS UNSIGNED) ) FROM `customers`
```

Comment: please fix the `uniqueI dAS UNSIGNED` to `uniqueId AS UNSIGNED`